# How to connect a PCoIP Hostcard to a DELL T3500 to enable remote power up?

Tags: dell-precision, pcoip

I want to integrate a EVGA HD02 PCoIP Hostcard into a DELL T3500.
The card itself and remote acces to the card works fine in the system, but now i would like to be able to remotley power on the machine.

The host card came with a cable that is supposed to be plugged onto the same pins that the original power button plugs into, but the machine, being a DELL, does not seem to have any pins where i could connect the cable. There is a ribbon cable running from a small PCB on the front panel to the mainboard, and thats all.

Directly next to the SATA ports are two places, where it seems somewhat likely that i could power up the machine. The first thing is what looks like two SMD pads. This thing is labeled SW_POWER. Directly next to it are two holes that look like a header could be soldered there, labeled PWR_REMOTE.

The Service Manual for that machine on the DELL homepage does not hold any information about those to "connectors". Googling proves equally futile.

The machine is out of warranty, so i personally would not mind soldering to those pads, but i do not want to damage the machine by experimenting what thone pads actally do.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally allowed by my boss to start experimenting on that machine.

I started with the holes marked as PWR_REMOTE, as i thought if those work they would be easier to solder to. I inserted a cable with a soldered header into those holes, applied power to the machine, and shorted the wires. And the machine started up on the first try. While still in POST, i shorted them again, and the machine turned of. As a last test, i let the machine boot to Windows, logged on, and shorted the wires again. As expected (and hoped), the machine started a normal shutdown, just as if the actual power button was pressed.
Finally sure that the thing worked as i wanted, i soldered a standard 2,54 mm header, onto which i could plug the cable from the PCoIP hostcard, to the board. I had to remove the mainboard from the case, this was possible without removing the CPU cooler.

Now everything is reassembled, and working fine.